# Finding nearest line/point from polygon using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, polygon, proximity

I have got the point and the polygon (or line). I have to find the closest coordinate (it can be the "virtual" point on edge) from polygon due to the point.

Do you know how to find out this coordinate?

[image: Point]

Comment: Try: http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=postgis_nearest_neighbor_generic#130

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html

ST_ClosestPoint — Returns the 2-dimensional point on g1 that is closest to g2. This is the first point of the shortest line.